# MultiSelectList doesn't return view data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a multi select list in my View to send to controller a list of Users. My View receives the users, but is not sending back to controller. What am I missing?

My controller is:

```
        // GET:
    public ActionResult Create(User user)
    {
        ViewModel model = new ViewModel();

        Interaction interact = new Interaction();

        model.Users= Repository.GetUsers();
        model.Interacao = interact;

        return View( model );
    }
```

In my view, the listBox is:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor( model => model.Users, new MultiSelectList( Model.Users, "Id", "Name" ) )
```

Can Anyone tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be binding with `model.Users` as first argument as this represents a list. The first argument need to be an array of string/integer which will contain the selected values:

Example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    pubilc string[] SelectedUserIds { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UserViewModel> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor( 
    model => model.SelectedUserIds, 
    new MultiSelectList(Model.Users, "Id", "Name") 
)
```

which will successfully bind to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string[] selectedUserIds) { ... }
```

or:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model) { ... }
```

but of course in the second case you will only get the `SelectedUserIds` property populated as that's the only thing sent from the view. If you need to redisplay the same view (due to model errors for example) you will need to repopulate the `Users` collection property of the vie model as it won't be persisted.